# Is it possible to pronounce jury as /dʒɜːri/?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, american-accent, vowels

sometimes I hear Americans pronounce jury as ''/dʒɜːri/''. Is that right? Is it regional or generally they say this way?

Comment: It's what's called ***nursing the cure*** (look it up).

Comment: Until you asked, I (AmE speaker) didn’t know there was any other way to pronounce it. Accents are like that.

Answer (score 1):

*CURE* represents /ʊə/ and *NURSE* represents /ɜː/ in [John Wells Standard Lexical Sets for English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_set)

> sometimes I hear Americans pronounce jury as ''/dʒɜːri/''. Is that right?

Yes, most American and some British accents have reduced the *CURE* vowel to the *NURSE* vowel and it is what's called ***Nursing the cure***.
For 'jury', [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jury) gives /ˈjər-ē/ as an alternative pronunciation.
For 'cure', Merriam-Webster gives /ˈkyər/ as an alternative pronunciation.

The /ə/ and the [*NURSE* vowel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-mid_central_unrounded_vowel) /ɜ/ are both central vowels are interchangeable for some people.
According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English-language_vowel_changes_before_historic_/r/#Cure%E2%80%93nurse_merger), it's probably because of the following /r/.

Answer (score 0):

> Maybe no Australians say **jury** with the NORTH/FORCE vowel, but some Brits do. A 1998 poll of British speakers reported in Wells (2000) shows 77% prefer /dʒʊəri/, 13% prefer /dʒɜːri/ (surprisingly enough; I thought that was a uniquely North American pronunciation), and 10% prefer /dʒɔːri/. Among those born since 1973, the numbers are about 55%, 25%, 20% respectively. --Angr/tɔk tə mi 08:08, 25 Jun 2005 (UTC)

[**Wikipedia article**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:International_Phonetic_Alphabet_for_English/Archive_2)

The common American way is **[ˈdʒʊri]** and the British is **[ˈdʒʊəri]**

[**Cambridge definition**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/jury)